# How do I inspect change-set data on the server before saving it?

Tags: breeze

A friend asks "Do you have examples or docs on how to inspect the Breeze change-set data on the server and perform server side validation and security checks before committing the data to the database?" My answer follows.

Answer (score 2):

See the "[Custom EFContextProvider](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider)" topic in the documentation which describes the Breeze.NET facilities for this purpose.

> *Although this topic targets the `EFContextProvider<T>` specifically, most of the points apply to the base class, `ContextProvider<T>`, which is helpful when saving to any kind of data store (see the ["NoDb" sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb) for example).*

The app produced by the **BreezeMvcSpa template** offers a taste of save validation (understood in the broadest sense to include security checks).

> *The BreezeMvcSpa template will be released Feb 2013 in conjunction with the "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2"*)

Look at Models/**TodoRepository.cs** which inherits from `EFContextProvider<T>`. It overrides **`BeforeSaveEntity(entityInfo)`** to confirm that you are always updating/deleting a `TodoList`/`TodoItem` that belongs to the current user. It also assigns the current user to a new `TodoList`. In a real app, this would be a dispatcher to some helper classes dedicated to validating specific entity types, a point I slightly elaborate below.

There are two other important overrides:

**`BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap)`** gives you a chance to examine the entire change-set at once. This is a great way to make validate the entire change-set as a whole perhaps to ensure that this save request makes sense as a single transaction. It's also a good place to do some cross-entity checking. `BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap)` is called after calling `BeforeSaveEntity(entityInfo)` for each entity individually.

`BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap)` might be a good dispatch point for delegating validation to dedicated helper classes. I doubt that I would put all of my validation logic in one big `ContextProvider` class. I don’t mind that all save activity funnels through the `ContextProvider.SaveChanges` gate but I don’t want to do all the work in the `ContextProvider` itself.

**`SaveChangesCore`** is the other important override. That’s where you do any final pre-save preparation and hand the change-set to something that actually performs the database save (e.g., the `DbContext.SaveChanges` method). You could intercept the result of the save operation before returning control to the `ContextProvider`.

Note also that, when using the `DbContext`, **EF applies the validations you prescribe in model attributes**, both the standard set and your custom validation attributes.

I have more save advice but this is probably enough to digest right now.